# Encrypting partition/volume using TrueCrypt

Tags: mac, partitioning, passwords, encryption, truecrypt

I'd like to password protect an existing partition on my mac using TrueCrypt.

I selected the partition using "**Select Device**", but I'm not sure what exactly is the process, can someone please tell me the steps briefly.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a volume (you probably want to select "Entire system drive")
- Follow instructions based on your preferences (example: multiboot options)
- Set encryption algorithm on volume
- Set volume password
- You will be prompted for a password before booting into the GUI as shown below:

[image]

- These instructions are for windows. Truecrypt does not currently support encryption of the entire system drive in OS X. (See documentation at http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/system-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

This blog has an a post titled "[Create an Encrypted Partition on Mac OS X using Truecrypt](http://www.nateclark.com/articles/2008/07/09/create-an-encrypted-partition-on-mac-os-x-using-truecrypt)".